# Redux saga devtool showing blank in chrome

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have installed Redux Saga Dev Tools and included the code:

````
const monitor = window.__SAGA_MONITOR_EXTENSION__;```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({ sagaMonitor: monitor });```
````

But redux saga devtool shows nothing and is blank.

React and Redux dev tools are working fine for me.

Details for the dev tool:

> Version
>   0.0.6
>   Updated  September 26, 2018
>   Size  123KiB
>   Language English
>   Redux-saga version - "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
>   "redux": "^4.0.0"
>   "react": "^16.4.1"

Please let me know how to get redux saga devtool working

Answer (score -1):

[Saga dev tool do not support new version of saga yet](https://spectrum.chat/react-boilerplate/general/on-dev-branch-redux-saga-dev-tools-no-longer-working~79003867-77d4-41bc-a5e4-49d5620c9bbf)

short: So you can use old version of saga (0.16.x)